# Fire Alarm Circuit using transistor

Tags: transistors, pcb-design, proteus, thermistor

This circuit is working inversely on PCB as compare to Proteus Software. In software, when the temperature increases the buzzer is on. This is the desired output, but on PCB this circuit is working inversely when the temperature increases the buzzer is off. How i can solve this problem?

[image: Fire Alarm Circuit on Proteus Software]

Comment: The thermistor turns off the transistor at high temperature by pulling the base towards ground. So, your hardware circuitry is fine. Both image and the observation on hardware matches!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've labeled your 'thermistor' RT1 as a KTY81. That device is not actually a thermistor - it is a 'silicon temperature sensor' http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/KTY81_SER.pdf

Have you actually used this particular device in your real circuit?

If you've used a 'normal' NTC thermistor instead then this would explain the behaviour of your circuit since the KTY81 is a PTC device.